# Save Multipart Image File Sent From Android to Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, android, file, laravel, upload

**UPDATE** The problem is solved. It was folder permission error. simple chmod corrected it.

The image gets sent easily. problem is , i am not able to save it to disk. 
I've tried several methods, but none working for me.

Here is Android Code

```
      mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures/msp/" + mIFileName);
        URL mUrl = new URL(mPostURL);
        HttpURLConnection mHttpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        mHttpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        //Write Post Data
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(mHttpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(mTwoHyphens + boundary + mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes(mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes(mIFileName);
        wr.writeBytes(mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes(mTwoHyphens + boundary + mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes(mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes("MSP Staff-Tailor-Merch Picture");
        wr.writeBytes(mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes(mTwoHyphens + boundary + mLineEnd);
        wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\";filename=\""
                + mIFileName +"\"" + mLineEnd + "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" +"\r\n");
        wr.writeBytes(mLineEnd);
```

Will someone kindly inform me how to read this uploaded image file in laravel 5.1 and save it to disk. (It's not base64 encoded).
Request::hasfile('image') returns True.
But any operation on file results in error.

Here is the laravel compact() output

```
{"reply":"success","title":"STAFF_faizan.png","description":"MSP Staff-Tailor-Merch Picture","photo":null,"filename":null}
```

And This one is laravel var_dump() out of all the Inputs.

```
["title"]=>  string(16) "STAFF_faizan.png"  ["description"]=>  string(30) "MSP Staff-Tailor-Merch Picture"  ["photo"]=>  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#29 (7) {    ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>    bool(false)    ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>    string(16) "STAFF_faizan.png"    ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>    string(10) "image/jpeg"    ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>    int(25617)    ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>    int(0)    ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>    string(14) "/tmp/phpG3oqEy"    ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>    string(9) "phpG3oqEy"  }}
```

Comment: Seems like the file gets into laravel nicely, put your laravel code here, need to see that.

Comment: Route::post('up',function(){

    $title = Input::get('title');
    $path = public_path() . '/uploads/';

    try {
        if(Request::hasFile('photo')){
            $photo = Request::file('photo');
            $photo->move($path,$title);
            $reply = 'File Uploaded';
        }else {
            $reply = 'File Not Found';
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $reply = $e;
    }

    return $reply;

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

`$photo = Request::file('photo');
$photo->move('/path/to/move', 'filename' . '.' . $photo->getExtention());`